# atof truncates fractional parts after QApplication

Tags: linux, qt, atof

I created a qt application with qt creator, the code is like,

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QApplication>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  double before = atof("3.1");
  double x;
  sscanf("3.1", "%lf", &x);
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  double after = atof("3.1");
  double y;
  sscanf("3.1", "%lf", &y);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();
  qDebug() <<  before;
  qDebug() <<  after;
  qDebug() <<  x;
  qDebug() <<  y;
  return a.exec();
}
```

the output is

```
3.1
3
3.1
3
```

That means sscanf and atof truncates fractional parts after "QApplication a(argc, argv);". The problem only occurs in Qt5.3 under Linux Mint 17. I tested the same program in windows 8 and Mac OS 10.9, they don't have the same problem. Is it a bug in Linux Qt5.3 or it has something to do with linux c library?

The complete code can be accessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4sxo8qgxeyhuin/atof_test.tar.gz)

Comment: Cannot reproduce... We need an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2):

See [QCoreApplication documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QCoreApplication.html):

> On Unix/Linux Qt is configured to use the system locale settings by
>   default. This can cause a conflict when using POSIX functions, for
>   instance, when converting between data types such as floats and
>   strings, since the notation may differ between locales. To get around
>   this problem, call the POSIX function setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,"C") right
>   after initializing QApplication or QCoreApplication to reset the
>   locale that is used for number formatting to "C"-locale.

I can reproduce your problem and the following code fixes it for me:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,"C");
```

Comment: To be more specific, in some locales decimal point is *not* `.` (it might be `,`). And both `scanf` and `atof` stop scanning at first illegal character, thus getting only `3` when the decimal point char in string is wrong for the locale.